# Ubuntu 18 , stuck at purple screen after log in , how to fix this?

Tags: intel-graphics

What I’ve tried so far : switch to lightdm , chamge grub default command line according to a reddit post ,  ute none worked , so I reversed the changes , my laptop : asus X541U. I wanted to try updating my graphics card drivers , but I couldn’t find the command for the intel ones

Comment: gmeerik [reinstalled Ubuntu fresh from a USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1074846/ubuntu-18-stuck-at-purple-screen-after-log-in-how-to-fix-this/1074856#comment1764559_1074856).

Answer (score 1):

As a temporary workaround, you may be able to log in by going to recovery mode, run 'grub', then run 'resume'.

What works for some having this problem is to add 'nomodeset'  to grub. To do this, run:

> sudo nano /etc/default/grub

and change this line:

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

to this:

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"

Exit (Ctrl X), save, and run:

> sudo update-grub

Comment: How do I go into recovery mode ? left shift advanced options ? I will try your recommendation as soon as I get home sir

Comment: You can enter Grub by holding 'right shift'  during boot. From the menu, select recovery mode.

(see also https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode)

Comment: now it’s an entirely black screen after log-in , and it feels really laggy and weird

Comment: well.. I'm not sure if I would be able to help you.. but for sure if someone does he/she would benefit from some additional information: 
1. You say you 'reversed the changes'. What changes?
2. Did you do a clean install of 18.04.01 or did you upgrade? And if so from what?
3. What did you already change in Grub?
4. Why do you think it has to do with the Intel drives? My experience is that the default drivers for Intel are just fine and do not benefit from manual updates unless you have very specific issues (very different from NVidia/AMD drivers).

Comment: I am installing a fresh from usb